# Как заставить JS видеть функции в конце файла?

Tags: javascript

Не могу назначить переменным значения возвращаемые функциями, если эти функции объявлены в коде ниже, чем переменные.

Ни в одном языке с таким не сталкивался, кроме клиентского JS. Подскажите, как решается проблема?

Код длинный, привожу в чём конкретно проявляется проблема:

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

console.log(f_result());

var f_add = function(){
    return x+y;
};
var f_multi = function(){
    return x*y;
};
var f_result = function(){
    return f_add() + f_multi();
};
```

Получаю ошибку:

> test_1.js:5056 Uncaught TypeError: f_result is not a function
>       at test_1.js:5056

---

**UPDATE**

---

**ОТВЕТ:**

Всего лишь нужно было привести в соответствие с последней спецификацией!

```
var x = 10;
var y = 20;

console.log(f_result());

function f_add(){
    return x+y;
};
function f_multi(){
    return x*y;
};
function f_result(){
    return f_add() + f_multi();
};
```

Так всё работает!

Comment: пример? *(7 символов нужно...)*

Comment: а код  покажите  ?

Comment: Добавил код, ответ уже дал некий Igor

Comment: _нужно было привести в соответствие с последней спецификацией!_ - это **НЕ** последняя спецификация. Определение функций так работало с самой первой версии языка

Answer (score 2):

Функция `test1` видна с первой строчки файла, хотя находится в конце:

```js
console.log(test1);
var a = test1();
console.log(a);

function test1() {
  return 123;
}
```

Переменная `test2` видна с первой строчки файла с значением `undefined`. Она становится равна функции после строчки `test2 = function...`.

```js
console.log(test2);
var a = test2();
console.log(a);

var test2 = function() {
  return 456;
}
```

Или Вы о таком говорите?

```html
<script>
var c = test3();
</script>
<script>
function test3() {
  return 789;
}
</script>
```